# Define a thmtools theorem in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I want to use `thmtools` inside a beamer document, to style theorems.

The MWE below gives the following error:

> Command \theorem already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

How to solve it?

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\normalfont\arial\bfseries, 
    notefont=\normalfont\arial\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    spaceabove=8pt,
    spacebelow=8pt
]{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section,style=definition]{theorem}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\Arial{Arial}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\TimesE{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\courier{Courier New}[Script=Latin,Language=English]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
We begin the lecture by stating a theorem:
\begin{theorem}[Euclid]
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2,3,5,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `notheorems` option to prevent beamer from defining them (and if you are at it, remove the `twoside` option. It makes absolutely no sense with beamer).

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\normalfont\arial\bfseries, 
    notefont=\normalfont\arial\bfseries,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    bodyfont = \normalfont,
    spaceabove=8pt,
    spacebelow=8pt
]{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section,style=definition]{theorem}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\Arial{Arial}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\TimesE{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\courier{Courier New}[Script=Latin,Language=English]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
We begin the lecture by stating a theorem:
\begin{theorem}[Euclid]
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2,3,5,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But, the font specifications (bold face, Arial type, for the head) are not used. How to fix it?

Comment: @tush `\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\normalfont\Arial\bfseries}}`

Comment: So is there any importance to the keys I pass to thmtools when I define a theorem style with `declaretheoremstyle`?

Comment: @tush Not really. You could just get rid of all this thmtools stuff and change the appropriate beamer settings to get whatever look you like for your theorems....

Comment: Where in beamer [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) can I find the different settings available?

Comment: See section "12.4 Theorem Environments" of the user guide. For colours and fonts, I find this short overview a bit easier to navigate https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf (just remember that internally the theorem uses a beamer block environment, thus you want to change the colour/fonts of the block)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141207/discussion-between-tush-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).